# oracle apex 5 user cannot submit changes

Tags: oracle-apex-5

I created user to my app in Oracle APEX 5. I have a form in my app, like bellow.

[image]

If the user I, as admin created, changes something in the form, then then is a blank page with address:

[image]

Can anybody help me out with that? I just need my app to accept users entry and go on as usual. Thaks in advance.

Comment: What else can you tell us about the page? Is it a modal dialog? Is there a branch on the page? Did you create the form using a wizard or manually?

Comment: It is a modal dialog and I created it using wizard. I finally solved it with  asking DBAs to restart APEX.